# Reset shinyjqui drag&drop orderinput

Tags: r, shiny, drag-and-drop, shinyjs

For this question I modified code (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/shinyjqui/readme/README.html)

I need to reset the orderinput based on clicking button "reset".

Example: If I drop *Nov* and *Dec* into **Dest** and then click on the button, I want the elements to be in **Source** again. Can I call the orderinputs by ID to reset them?

```
  server <- function(input, output) {
  output$order <- renderPrint({ print(input$dest_order) })

  observeEvent(input$btn,{
    reset("dest")        # these did not work
    reset("input$dest")
    reset(input$dest)
  })
}

ui <- fluidPage(
  orderInput('source', 'Source', items = month.abb,
             connect = 'dest'),
  orderInput('dest', 'Dest', items = NULL, placeholder = 'Drag items here...', connect = 'source'),
  verbatimTextOutput('order'),

  actionButton("btn","reset")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue with the orderInput widget not reacting to reset() or updateSelectInput().

I ended up using a work around in which the ui of the orderInput widget is re-rendered, upon pressing the reset button. This was based on the answer of another stackoverflow question ([Maximum item in shinyjqui::orderInput](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47902288/maximum-item-in-shinyjquiorderinput)).

If I understand your case correctly, you would like both the source and dest orderInput widgets to be reset to their initial values when the reset button is pressed:

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjqui)

server <- function(input, output) {
      output$order <- renderPrint({ print(input$dest_order) })


      output$ui_source <- renderUI({
                orderInput('source', 'Source', items = month.abb,
                           connect = 'dest')
      })

      output$ui_dest <- renderUI({
                orderInput('dest', 'Dest', items = NULL, placeholder = 'Drag items here...', connect = 'source')
      })


      observeEvent(input$btn,{
                # Render the UI for the orderInput widgets again
                output$ui_source <- renderUI({
                          orderInput('source', 'Source', items = month.abb,
                                     connect = 'dest')
                })

                output$ui_dest <- renderUI({
                          orderInput('dest', 'Dest', items = NULL, placeholder = 'Drag items here...', connect = 'source')
                })

      })
}

ui <- fluidPage(

      uiOutput("ui_source"),

      uiOutput("ui_dest"),

      verbatimTextOutput('order'),

      actionButton("btn","reset")
)

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: +1 for a great answer. Also love that this avoids any id/element namespace collision since you're essentially recreating the UI elements.